# Trim both newlines and spaces in VBA 7.0

Tags: vba

Trim (in VBA for MS-Access 2010) does not remove vbCrLfs, only spaces.  In the immediate window, I get

```
? Len(vbCrLf & "a" & vbCrLf & "b" & vbCrLf)
 8 

? Len(Trim(vbCrLf & "a" & vbCrLf & "b" & vbCrLf))
 8
```

For spaces however:

```
? Len(" " & "a" & " " & "b" & " ")
 5 

? Len(Trim(" " & "a" & " " & "b" & " "))
 3
```

How to make a trim that removes vbCrLFs on the ends only?

Comment: hey mate, how did you manage to ask and answer exactly at the same time? That's cool.

Comment: Yes, there is a checkbox when you ask a question: "Answer your own question".

Comment: ah.... didn't notice that before. good .

Comment: I don't understand why this got voted down.  If the down voters could at least leave feedback, that be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seems to have done the trick:

```
Public Function trimNewlinesAndSpaces(chaine As String) As String
    chaine = Trim(chaine)

    Do While (left(chaine, 2) = vbCrLf) Or right(chaine, 2) = vbCrLf
        If left(chaine, 2) = vbCrLf Then
            chaine = right(chaine, Len(chaine) - 2)
        End Ifj

        If right(chaine, 2) = vbCrLf Then
            chaine = left(chaine, Len(chaine) - 2)
        End If

        chaine = Trim(chaine)
    Loop

    trimNewlinesAndSpaces = chaine
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind removing ALL new lines (and not just edges) you could just do:

```
myStr = Application.clean(Application.trim(myStr))
```

For imitating Trim function, you'd need to test each character in your string's edges:

```
Function TrimNewLines(mtStr As String) As String
    Dim pattern As String, c As String
    Dim i As Integer: i = 1
    pattern = "[" & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & "]"
    c = Mid(mtStr, i, 1)
    Do While c Like pattern
        i = i + 1
        c = Mid(mtStr, i, 1)
    Loop
    mtStr = Mid(mtStr, i, Len(mtStr))
    i = Len(mtStr)
    c = Mid(mtStr, i, 1)
    Do While c Like pattern
        i = i - 1
        c = Mid(mtStr, i, 1)
    Loop
    mtStr = Mid(mtStr, 1, i)
    TrimNewLines = mtStr
End Function
```